# How to scrape info off a website if there is a "show more" button?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl a website with a show more button, and I'm having trouble getting the info that shows up after you click the "show more".

Currently, I'm trying to crawl the links of all the articles in this website:"https://www.nytimes.com/section/world"

I've managed to use selenium to click on the "show more" button, but I am still unable to get the extra links. Here's what I have so far:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/cherlin/Documents/北大/大一/文计/期末大作业/程序/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.nytimes.com/section/world")

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="latest-panel"]/div[1]/div/div/button').click()
links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.story-link')
```

The links shows up as a list of 40 webelements. I'm still trying to figure out how to get the actual links, but I need to figure out how to get the hidden links first.

Comment: Open your browser's inspector and go to the Network tab. Click "Show more" button on the web page and note which URL it requests. Scrape that URL.

Comment: @Selcuk the return of that URL is actually a JSON, which should make it even easier to process!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done using the `requests` library to grab the JSON data:

```
import requests

page = 0
items = [' ']   # start non-empty

while items:
    data = {"q" : "", "sort" : "newest", "page" : page, "dom" : "www.nytimes.com", "dedupe_hl" : "y"}
    r = requests.get("https://www.nytimes.com/svc/collections/v1/publish/www.nytimes.com/section/world", params=data)
    json_data = r.json()
    items = json_data['members']['items']
    
    for item in items:
        print(f"{item['headline'][:50]:50}  {item['url']}")
        
    page += 1
```

This would give you an output starting:

```
Lunar Eclipse and Supermoon: Photos From Around th  https://www.nytimes.com/2019/01/21/science/lunar-eclipse-supermoon.html
By the Numbers, China’s Economy Is Worse Than It L  https://www.nytimes.com/2019/01/20/business/china-economy-gdp-fourth-quarter.html
Henry Sy, the Philippines’ Richest Man and a Shopp  https://www.nytimes.com/2019/01/20/world/asia/henry-sy-dead.html
Carlos Ghosn Offers Higher Bail and Security Guard  https://www.nytimes.com/2019/01/20/business/carlos-ghosn-bail-japan.html
American Airstrike in Somalia Kills 52 Shabab Extr  https://www.nytimes.com/2019/01/20/world/africa/airstrike-shabab-somalia.html
```

This approach will be much faster than using selenium. The loop continues requesting more pages until `0` items are returned.

Comment: wow thanks! I actually tried selenium and its quite slow, I have to continuously scroll down to get more info! I think i give this a try :')

Comment: Why do you have `range(3)` and a `for` loop? Also, is the URL you included a function of nytimes.com? `https://www.nytimes.com/svc/collections/v1/publish/www.nytimes.com/section/world`

I'm looking to extrapolate this to another website with a "Show More" button.

Comment: @grantog, the `range(3)` was just an example to show an alternative approach to using selenium. I have updated it to show how all items could be displayed using a `while True` loop.